# The view bookmarks.views.register_page didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

can anyone please identify the problem
please help me out

```
def register_page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
        variables = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form
        })
        return render_to_response(
            'registration/register.html',
            variables
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem. Everything from `else` onwards should be moved one indentation to the left. Otherwise, as the error says, nothing is returned when method is not POST.